# Is it possible to create (NOT import) a new class in java using BeanShell?

Tags: java, android, interpreter, beanshell

I use BeanShell to dynamically manage interface and content in my android application. Today I faced the following problem: I need to process a class with an unknown structure for the application, that is, the server sends the code and the application processes it.

Below is one of my code handlers. The error is reported to the "**public class LastNews{**":

```
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import java.util.Random;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import apppackege.ViewCreator;
    import apppackege.Calculate;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import apppackege.AdapterCreator;
    import apppackege.IconName;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
    import apppackege.WrappingGridView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import apppackege.Decoder;
    import apppackege.LoadImage;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    LinearLayout topPanel = ViewCreator.linearLayout(context, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Calculate.dpToPixel(context, 40)), LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    topPanel.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1E88E5"));

    LinearLayout bottomPanel = ViewCreator.linearLayout(context, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Calculate.dpToPixel(context, 40)), LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    bottomPanel.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EFEFEF"));

    ScrollView scrollView = ViewCreator.scrollView(context, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
    scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    parent.addView(topPanel);
    parent.addView(scrollView);
    parent.addView(bottomPanel);

    LinearLayout scrollLayout = ViewCreator.linearLayout(context,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), -1);
    scrollView.addView(scrollLayout);

    ImageView topImage = ViewCreator.imageView(context, null, null);
    new LoadImage(topImage, "https://url.com/9tVFtRoOCIQ.jpg");
    scrollLayout.addView(topImage);

    WrappingGridView wrappingGridView = ViewCreator.wrappingGridView(context, null, 3);
    scrollLayout.addView(wrappingGridView);
    String jsonIconName = "[{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/thumb-up.png\",\"name\":\"ГОЛОС\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/news.png\",\"name\":\"НОВОСТИ\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/camping-tent.png\", \"name\": \"ТУРИЗМ\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/image.png\",\"name\":\"ФОТО\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/cafe.png\",\"name\":\"МЕСТА\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/user.png\",\"name\":\"АККАУНТ\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/cinema-.png\",\"name\":\"АФИША\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/focal-length.png\",\"name\":\"КОНТРОЛЬ\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"},{\"icon\":\"https://url.com/chase.png\",\"name\":\"ОХОТА\",\"iconColor\":\"#1E88E5\"}]";
    BaseAdapter baseAdapter = AdapterCreator.baseAdapterIconName(context, Decoder.fromJsonArray(jsonIconName, IconName.class));
    wrappingGridView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
    ((BaseAdapter)wrappingGridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();

    TextView lineActual = ViewCreator.textView(context, "АКТУАЛЬНО",
            null, 10, 14, "#1E88E5", new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "АКТУАЛЬНО", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    scrollLayout.addView(lineActual);

    TextView lineNews = ViewCreator.textView(context, "СВЕЖИЕ НОВОСТИ",
            null, 10, 14, "#1E88E5", new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "СВЕЖИЕ НОВОСТИ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    scrollLayout.addView(lineNews);
    String jsonNews = " [ { \"id\": \"89e94f07-2939-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Белорус сделал предложение Бузовой в прямом эфире X Factor\", \"icon\": \"http://url.com/73fde9f1-a72f-43c0-a6e7-10957e216a9b.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://url.com/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cf1-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Жители Приморья стоят в очередях за белорусскими продуктами - Богданов\", \"icon\": \"http://url.com/77e75355-4255-4cae-9962-fdb7394986c5.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://url.com/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cf0-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Помолодел и стал жестким – глава Минздрава о четвертой волне коронавируса\", \"icon\": \"http://url.com/f28b5349-e639-4250-9391-7ad88fcf4946.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://url.com/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cef-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Так было или не было? Серега ответил о своем романе с Бузовой\", \"icon\": \"http://url.com/10-2021/60cc9d51-f570-4e68-bada-4ba4aab92bcb.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://url.com/info.png\", \"location\": \"Минск\" }, { \"id\": \"6088c966-2920-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Работа ТЭЦ в Минске восстановлена - Минэнерго\", \"icon\": \"http://url.com/01b6db5f-8305-4e86-9d9a-f59cc2be2787.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://url.com/info.png\", \"location\": \"Минск\" } ]";

    public class LastNews{
        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;
        @SerializedName("head")
        public String head;
        @SerializedName("icon")
        public String icon;
        @SerializedName("type")
        public String type;
        @SerializedName("location")
        public String location;
    }

    LinearLayout listNews = ViewCreator.linearLayout(context, null, -1);
    ArrayList<Object> news = Decoder.fromJsonArray(jsonNews, LastNews.class);
    for(int i = 0; i < news.size(); i++){

        LastNews lastNews = (LastNews) news.get(i);

        //crate view and add to "listNews"

    }
```

Error message is:

```
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import android.widget.LinearLayout;         import android.widget.ScrollView;    . . . '' unknown error: can't load this type of class file : at Line: 75 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import android.widget.LinearLayout;         import android.widget.ScrollView;    . . . '' : public class LastNews {
```

Can you tell me if such an implementation is possible using BeanShell? If so, is it possible to have an example of such functionality?

Comment: Java is a compiled language; so probably not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hmm ... this is very strange, because structuring a class does not require static. Most likely, its structure for a binshell should look a little different, but so far I don't know what it should be ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, but not by sending the text of the class file.  Java is a compiled language.  You'd need to send the .class file, or the equivalent that the most recent android Java interpreter used (is it .dex still?).  Then you'd need to load it via a custom class loader.  Basically you're going to be doing dark magic and really need to know Java, it's class structure, and how the interpreter works to do it.

A couple of warnings about this:

1)It won't be allowed on Google play.  Google does not allow dynamically loaded code in apps on their store.

2)It's a massive security hole. This is part of why #1 is the case.

3)It becomes a major source of bugs over time, as code changes.  You now have to worry not just about "does my release work" but "does my release work with every possible version of this downloaded code it may need to interact with".  And also "If a version was skipped, will the data structure still be compatible, even if a version was skipped".  There's additional possibility for security bugs here.

Comment: thanks for the information. I think you are completely right, and transferring *.class files is not very profitable for me ..

About your warnings:
1. I agree here, but I think I'll be able to bypass their application verification system.
2. Yes, at first glance this is exactly the case, but the purpose of dynamic code is to secure the application itself.
3. Perhaps this is how it will eventually happen. However, the application is still in the development stage of the entire core, which will eventually become the basis for the application to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided to me. I made the most convenient decision. I excluded the classes themselves from processing.

Therefore, now I will use the "Object" itself, for its further processing. If in the future someone needs a similar solution, then in my opinion the most compact would be to use such objects as "Object" and "LinkedTreeMap".

Here is the result of what I ended up sketching, below I will expand the modified example code:

```
    //...here is all the imported data

    //...the code from my first example

    String jsonNews = " [{\"id\":\"89e94f07-2939-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\",\"head\":\"Белорус сделал предложение Бузовой в прямом эфире X Factor\", \"icon\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/10-2021/73fde9f1-a72f-43c0-a6e7-10957e216a9b.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/ICONS/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cf1-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Жители Приморья стоят в очередях за белорусскими продуктами - Богданов\", \"icon\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/10-2021/77e75355-4255-4cae-9962-fdb7394986c5.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/ICONS/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cf0-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Помолодел и стал жестким – глава Минздрава о четвертой волне коронавируса\", \"icon\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/10-2021/f28b5349-e639-4250-9391-7ad88fcf4946.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/ICONS/info.png\", \"location\": \"Беларусь\" }, { \"id\": \"c2833cef-2928-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Так было или не было? Серега ответил о своем романе с Бузовой\", \"icon\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/10-2021/60cc9d51-f570-4e68-bada-4ba4aab92bcb.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/ICONS/info.png\", \"location\": \"Минск\" }, { \"id\": \"6088c966-2920-11ec-a3ee-e145f6ad5670\", \"head\": \"Работа ТЭЦ в Минске восстановлена - Минэнерго\", \"icon\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/10-2021/01b6db5f-8305-4e86-9d9a-f59cc2be2787.jpg\", \"type\": \"http://45.147.199.147/IMAGES/FOTO/ICONS/info.png\", \"location\": \"Минск\" } ]";
    LinearLayout listNews = ViewCreator.linearLayout(context, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ArrayList news = Decoder.fromJsonArray(jsonNews, null);
    for(int i=0; i < news.size(); i++){
        TextView newsHead = ViewCreator.textView(context, news.get(i).get("head"),
        null, 10, 14, "#1E88E5", new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, news.get(i).get("id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        listNews.addView(newsHead);
    }
    scrollLayout.addView(listNews);
```

Please note the way of converting json, it is converted into an array of objects, where each object is a "LinkedTreeMap":

```
public class Decoder {

    public static ArrayList<Object> fromJsonArray(String json, Class typeClass){
        try{
            if(typeClass != null) {
                return new Gson().fromJson(json, TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, typeClass).getType());
            }
            return new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Object>>() {}.getType());
        } catch (Exception ex){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, my test class had a task to look like this:

```
public class LastNews{
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("head")
    public String head;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    public String icon;
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;
    @SerializedName("location")
    public String location;
}
```

Now, when working with the "LinkedTreeMap" element, to get its variables, you use the following (analogue of the "[]" brackets):

```
news.get(i).get("head")
```

In conclusion, I want to say that this solution has a more compact form, because there will be no need to transfer and store classes.
I would like to add that the task of the application is to be as secure as possible in order to exclude the possibility of its hacking as much as possible. After all, the application will be at the state level.

Perhaps at the moment my decision is not correct. I will most likely face a lot of problems later on.